# DOCTYPE not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, doctype

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"         
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
     <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma"  content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">

        <Script language = JavaScript>
            function addOptionList(selectbox,text,value )
            {
                var optn = document.createElement('OPTION');
                optn.text = text;
                optn.value = value;
                selectbox.options.add(optn);
            }
            function removeOptionList(listbox,i){
                listbox.remove(i);
            }
            function addOption_list(fromvar,tovar){ 
                for(i=fromvar.options.length-1;i>=0;i--)    {
                    var userlist=fromvar;
                    if(fromvar[i].selected){
                        addOptionList(tovar, fromvar[i].value, fromvar[i].value);
                        removeOptionList(userlist,i);

                    }
                }
            }

        </Script>

    <table align='center'>
        <tr>
            <td ><select multiple name='userlist' id='userlist' >
                <option value='aaa'>aaa</option>
                <option value='bbb'>bbb</option>                
            </select></td>
            <td align='center' valign='middle'>
                <input value='--&gt;'  
                     onClick='addOption_list(userlist,pouser);' type='button'>
                <br><input value='&lt;--' 
                     onClick='addOption_list(pouser,userlist);' type='button'></td>
            <td><select multiple  name='pouser' id='pouser'>
                <option id='test' value='ccc'>ccc</option>              
            </select></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</HTML>
```

I am using the code above to select a name from left box and move it to the right box. The code is working in IE with/without DOCTYPE. But when I use DOCTYPE, it stops working in Firfox. I have spent a lot of time on it, but still couldn't figure out the problem. Also, I am a novice in Javascript, so please explain me the problem with code below (when I am using DOCTYPE). Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

You're relying on elements with ids showing up as global properties on the window (e.g. `userlist`).  Firefox only does that in quirks mode, which is why the doctype matters.

Comment: Thanks BOris. So how do I define it locally? Please let me know.Thanks!!

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("userlist")`

Answer (score 0):

Your markup does not match the DOCTYPE. I.e. you are not using valid XHTML 1.0 markup.

Paste you code [into the xhtml validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and it will show you what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks Griffina. Below pasted is the validated code from XHTML validator. It's still not working.:-( It's not letting me paste my updated code.